# How can I determine the installed edition of Windows 8 if the OS does not boot up?

Tags: windows-8

I have a drive that I cannot boot, but it has an installation of Windows 8 on it. I need to know what type of Windows 8 it has. Is there a folder or file I can look at that might give me a clue as to the flavor of 8 (Standard, Pro, Enterprise, or RT) I need to use for a recovery installation?

Since the OS is not booting even in safe mode I can only use command prompt.
Thanks.

Comment: You can also look on the device itself for the COA sticker.

Answer (score 0):

It will be stored in the registry. You can load the registry hive through another Windows installation.

Usually the registry is stored in `C:\windows\system32\config\`. You will need the file `software`. Make a copy of this somewhere for temporary use.

1. Open regedit: <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> -> `regedit`
2. Click on `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE`
3. Click `File` -> `Load hive`
4. Navigate to your copy of `software`
5. Give it any name, but NOT software (I don't think it would let you do that anyway. Call it `recover` for the sake of this example.
6. Navigate to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\recover\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\`
7. In here you should find all the version information you need.

To give you an example, on my machine I get:

`Product Name: Windows 10 Pro`

`Edition ID: Professional`

8. When you're done, click on `recover` again, followed by `File` and `Unload Hive`